# having issue with loading circle

Tags: c#

I want to show loading circle while doing some processing.
I am using MRG.Conrol right now.
Loading.cs file contains MRG.Controls.UI.LoadingCircle.

here is the sample application. here problem is loading circle not appears in circular motion.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace LoadingCircle
{
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Loading loding = new Loading();
        loding.SetText = "loading circle";
        loding.Show(this); //this form contains MRG conrol in it.
        loding.Refresh();

        int i = 1;
       // here i have some custom logic which takes 2 min to done.
       // i cant make this logic in separate thread.

        loding.Close();

    }      
}
```

}

Comment: This is probably because the Loading Circle is using a timer (based on window messages) and your `while` loop is blocking its thread. So no window messages will be handled. If you put your workingload on another thread (your while loop), it will update the loading circle.

Comment: Also can you elaborate more on why you can't make lengthy operation on background thread ?